# Classification techniques on histograms

Tags: classification, clustering, references

I have sets of different histograms that I wish to apply on them some classification techniques (e.g., PCA, LDA (linear discriminant analysis)) in order to cluster them. Therefore, what are the common and advised methods?

Furthermore, where can I find good tutorial and explanations about the advised methods as I am a beginner in this field?

Comment: I think you have to reconsider and narrow down it - what you really want. The three things - PCA, LDA, clustering - are quite different. LDA needs 'supervisor' classes while clustering needs not. PCA is a feature reduction method which only marginally relates to classification.

Comment: @user2676173: What is the purpose of your analysis? This might help to understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 1 - My data is image histograms, 2 - I seek  a method to perform clustering (without 'supervisor' classes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mix up classification and clustering. Classification needs *labeled data*, and will put objects into *predefined* classes.

The key question for dealing with histograms, in particular color histograms when using image data, is the *similarity function* to use.

Quadratic form distances are very good, but rather costly to compute; so this won't scale up to large data sets very well. Histogram intersection distance is much cheaper, and when your histograms are normalized (i.e. they all sum up to 1.0), it actually reduces to Manhattan distance.

Manhattan distance is nice, as it can be accelerated well using index structures. I've ran [OPTICS clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm) on 100k color histograms in 27 dimensions in just a few minutes, using [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/), by using bulk-loaded R*-tree indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there a R version for OPTICS clustering?. I will refine my problem, I have different histogram of color or gray-scale images (known samples) and I wish to cluster them via groups (e.g., images of blue sky, sand desert, etc). Therefore are there any another method recommendations.

Comment: I don't use R. I tried DBSCAN in R, and it was *much* slower, even without indexes. Anything that is not a matrix multiplication seems to be slow in R.

Comment: You can try DBSCAN, though. Or hierarchical linkage clustering.